# Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented. Where is the error when running

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, init

[image: Picture of code]

I don't understand how to fix the error. If someone understands please help!

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")
    let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bulletSound.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

    var gameArea: CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize)
    {
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height/maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth)/2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)
        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

I'm trying to set boundaries for the objects on the screen. When I wrote `super.init(size: size)`, Xcode automatically created required `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, but when it runs I get the error of:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented

Comment: I just added some more information. I implemented the code Xcode told me to, but when I run it I keep getting the Fatal error

Comment: Presumably, your scene is contained in a storyboard.  The `init(coder:)` initialiser is used in this case,  not `init(size:)`. You could add the required code to the `init(coder)`  initialiser, but it is probably better to add appropriate constraints to your storyboard - An aspect ratio constraint of your scene's width to its height, along with top and bottom constraints would probably work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented error despite being implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966565/fatal-error-initcoder-has-not-been-implemented-error-despite-being-implement)

Comment: See the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966583/4844273 It may be a case of just adding the line super.init(coder: aDecoder) above the line: fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

Answer (score 0):

Because you have overridden the designated initializer for SKScene with your `override init(size: CGSize)` method and therefore have to implement this `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method to allow the custom SKScene class (your GameScene class), object serialization.

This older article might help explain this for you:

[What exactly is init coder aDecoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386339/what-exactly-is-init-coder-adecoder)

If you are trying to initialize the `gameArea` variable, why not just try something like setting `gameArea` in an override of `sceneDidLoad()`? (really awful code below):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")
    let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bulletSound.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

    var gameArea: CGRect?

    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height/maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth)/2

        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)
    }

    <<more of your code>>
}
```

and eliminate the `override init(size: CGSize)`

Answer (score 0):

Like oaccamsrazor states, if you add an initializer to your class, you also have to implement any required initializers in the superclass.  The fact that you're hitting `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` indicates `init(size: ...)` isn't getting called, likely because you're creating your scene from an `.sks` file.

`init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will get called when creating your scene from an `.sks` file, so you can't have `fatalError()` there.  Basically, just actually implement your initializer if you have anything to initialize.  Otherwise, delete all your initializers and the requirement to have `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will disappear.