# getting initialization error when trying to segue or instantiate to vc

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, stripe-payments, nscoder

So my goal is to do a data transfer to the `CheckoutViewController()` that Stripe provides for their API. So as normal, I went to storyboards and connected a new vc with the `CheckoutViewController()` class so I can segue to it from my other vc and do a data transfer.

Before this, I was just pushing the vc, and it was working normally and knew I could instantiate it and do a data transfer as well, but even when I try to do it, I get a fatal error saying :

```
Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented
```

This is the code I have in the `CheckoutVC`:

```
let paymentContext: STPPaymentContext?
let config: STPPaymentConfiguration

let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())

init() {
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
    let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .name
    self.paymentContext = paymentContext
    self.config = config
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.paymentContext?.delegate = self
    self.paymentContext?.hostViewController = self
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I changed the `required init` because I read [this post on init errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966565/fatal-error-initcoder-has-not-been-implemented-error-despite-being-implement) but now it gives an error before even running saying:

```
Property 'self.paymentContext' not initialized at super.init call
```

This was all working before I connected the class to a vc in the storyboard, but I literally have no choice, I need to do a data transfer for users to pay the right amount. I don't get how the `self.paymentContext` wasn't initialized, I was using this just fine before. Does anybody know how I can solve this or work around it?

```
init() {
   
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
    let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .name
    self.paymentContext = paymentContext
    self.config = config
    self.paymentContext?.delegate = self
    self.paymentContext?.hostViewController = self
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way buddy explained it above really just tripped me out, but eventually I realized he was basically right, all I needed to do was this:

```
let paymentContext: STPPaymentContext
let config: STPPaymentConfiguration

let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
    let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .name
    self.paymentContext = paymentContext
    self.config = config
    super.init(coder: aDecoder )
    self.paymentContext.delegate = self
    self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self
}
```

Works good now.

Answer (score 0):

When coming out a storyboard it’s initWithCoder: that is called, not your init() function, and your implementation of initWithCoder calls super before initing all properties

It may be helpful to make a function called commonInit and have all the different initWith..s call commonInit, so your view controller can be instantiated programatically or from nibs etc

Comment: so instead of `init()` by itself do `init(with coder: NSCoder)`? Could you add a code snippet? @Shadowrun

Comment: I'm looking through all these SO post about `initWithCoder`, and it's all from like 2013 and it's objective-C code, can I still use this in Swift 5? @Shadowrun

Comment: Just take everything from your init apart from the super.init call and put it in your init with coder, before the super.initWithCoder call

Comment: Check the edit i made and see if that's correct. @Shadowrun